# Compilation Error: 'void' type not allowed here

Tags: java, compiler-errors, void

How can I resolve this type of a compilation error.

The bold part is the place where it shows a compilation error.

```
DegreeDays.java:71: 'void' type not allowed here
        System.out.println(***"\t"***(error here) +
            list(test[counter]) + "\t\t\t" + 
            average_temp(test[counter], test[counter - 1]));

DegreeDays.java:71: 'void' type not allowed here
        System.out.println("\t" + list(test[counter]) ***+
            ***(error here) "\t\t\t" + 
            average_temp(test[counter], test[counter - 1]));
```

Answer (score 4):

Imagine this:

```
void foo() {
  // doesn't matter
}

System.out.println("" + foo()); // What should happen here?
```

The answer is **explode** - and this is what javac is correctly doing. The method `foo` has a "void result type" (none, nada, zilch). There is no object returned. Ever. Not even null. There is "nothing" and the compiler will refuse to try and use "nothing" as a "something".

(A method with a "void result type" is different than a method which *can* return `null` -- e.g. return type is Object - such a method still has a "non-void" result type.)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

It seems most likely that `list` and `average_temp` aren't returning a `string`.

Comment: they don't have to return a string.  they would implicitly have the .toString() method called on them since the compiler has already determined that the string concatenation operation is being performed (it sees the + operator with at least 1 operand it can tell is a string).

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.print()` must need something to show. So if you write any `void` method in it which doesn't return anything it will show error.

So in your code:

```
System.out.println("\t" + list(test[counter]) + "\t\t\t" + average_temp(test[counter], test[counter - 1]));
```

I think `average_temp` is of type `void`.

Answer (score 0):

you try to print method return Nothing (void).

I think it is `list()` method check if it's return a `string` or `void` ..

if it return `void` you have to delete it from the `println` method..